# #1054 - Unknown column - given error, whereas the column DOES exist

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
INSERT INTO  `database_name`.`table_3` (
    `value_id` ,
    `entity_type_id` ,
    `attribute_id` ,
    `store_id` ,
    `entity_id` ,
    `value`
)
SELECT NULL, 4, attribute_id_values.attribute_id, 0, table_3.entity_id, table_1.value
FROM table_4
    INNER JOIN table_1 ON table_3.entity_id = table_1.entity_id
    INNER JOIN table_1 ON table_2.value_id = table_1.value_id AND table_2.store_id = 0 AND table_2.position = 0
    CROSS JOIN
    (
       SELECT 85 AS attribute_id
    UNION
       SELECT 86 AS attribute_id
    UNION
       SELECT 87 AS attribute_id
    ) AS attribute_id_values
    WHERE table_3.sku IN ('20710','3280401s')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE table_3.value = table_1.value
```

The field list:

[image]

So, I am getting this error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'table_3.entity_id' in 'field list'
```

And I surely don't see why this problem occurs, whereas I DO have the column in the certain table... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `table_3` is nowhere in the `FROM` list (i.e. `FROM` or `JOIN`).

I **think** you were maybe trying to do this:

```
SELECT NULL, 4, attribute_id_values.attribute_id, 0, table_3.entity_id, table_1.value
FROM table_1
    INNER JOIN table_3 ON table_3.entity_id = table_1.entity_id
    INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_2.value_id = table_1.value_id AND table_2.store_id = 0 AND table_2.position = 0
    CROSS JOIN
    (
       SELECT 85 AS attribute_id
    UNION
       SELECT 86 AS attribute_id
    UNION
       SELECT 87 AS attribute_id
    ) AS attribute_id_values
    WHERE table_3.sku IN ('20710','3280401s')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE table_3.value = table_1.value
```

Comment: The same is true for `table_2`.

Comment: @FrankPl, good eye. I'm going to post what I *think* the OP wanted.